# Has F1 Help Integration Been Accomplished with Visual Studio 2017 and wxWidgets?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, wxwidgets

Is there a help integration package that can make wxWidgets documentation available through F1 help in Visual Studio 2017?

To be specific, if I were to click on a wxWindow class in Visual Studio 2017's editor, it would be great if the wxWindow Class Reference page would just pop up.

I found some data online on integrating the wxWidgets help data into VS 2008, but as I recall the help subsystem has had an overhaul since then, and I don't want to do a bunch of download/install/grinding only to find that the result doesn't go into VS 2017.

Thanks in advance for knowledge you have on this.

Comment: Nope. Copying the word you need into the search box of [wx doc page](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/) may be enough.

Comment: Thx.  That's what I've been doing; it just adds a few seconds and a bit more distraction.  Sigh.